# Combine similar elements in N*N matrix without duplicates

Tags: python, nlp, word-embedding, sentence-similarity

I have a list of sentences, and I want to find all the sentences similar to it and put them together in a list/tuple.

I formed sentence embeddings for them, then computed an N*N cosine similarity matrix for N sentences. I then iterated through the elements, and picked the ones higher than a threshold.

If `sentences[x]` is similar to `sentences[y]` and `sentences[z]`, if I combine `sentences[x]` and `sentences[y]`, `sentences[x]` should not combine with `sentences[z]` as the loop iterates further

I went with the intuition that since we are comparing cosine similarities, if X is similar to Y, and Y is similar to Z, X will be similar to Z as well, so I should not have to worry about it. My goal is to not have duplicates, but I am stuck.

Is there a better way / what's the best way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sentence_transformers.util import cos_sim, pytorch_cos_sim

embedding_model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
threshold = 0.75

def form_embeddings(sentences, embedding_model=embedding_model):

    if isinstance(sentences, str):
        sentences = [sentences]

    return embedding_model.encode(sentences, convert_to_tensor=True)

df = pd.read_csv('sample_file.csv')
sentences = df['sentences'].tolist()

#form embeddings
sentence_embeddings = form_embeddings(sentences=sentences)

#form similarity matrix
sim_matrix = pytorch_cos_sim(sentence_embeddings, sentence_embeddings)

#set similarity with itself as zero
sim_matrix.fill_diagonal_(0)

#iterate through and find pairs of similarity
pairs = []
for i in range(len(sentences)):
    for j in range(i, len(sentences)):
        if sim_matrix[i,j] >= threshold:
            pairs.append({'index':[i,j], 'score': sim_matrix[i,j], 'original_sentence':sentences[i], 'similar_sentence':sentences[j]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a better way to do this.

This is solved by a [fast clustering implementation](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/applications/clustering/fast_clustering.py).

Answer (score 0):

*I went with the intuition that since we are comparing cosine similarities, if X is similar to Y, and Y is similar to Z, X will be similar to Z as well*

Sentence embeddings usually have high dimensions (e.g. 768), and it's like a black box for me to figure out the information of different dimensions. Therefore, even if sent[x] is similar to sent[y], and sent[y] is similar to sent[z], we cannot infer with confidence that sent[x] and sent[z] should also be combined, cause you don't know how each dimension contributes to their similarity.

In case you want to get non-duplicate sentence pairs, you can try **itertools.combinations()**